# How align Table column on decimal point yet use text styling?

Tags: list-manipulation, alignment

Form a table such as:

```
 data = Transpose[{Range[0, 5], RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 6]}];
```

Display it by wrapping with `TableForm`.

Is there some way to align the 2nd column on the decimal point and yet still be able to style the entries' font properties?

In other words, some way to combine the `TableAlignments -> "."` option of `TableForm` and apply `Style` or `Text` to the entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is enough to apply a uniform style to the whole table, then that can be achieved after applying `TableForm`:

```
data = Transpose[{Range[9, 14], RandomReal[{-5, 20}, 6]}];
Style[
 TableForm[data, TableAlignments -> "."],
 Red, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 23
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect! (And the one possibility I didn't think of.) I note that the same things works on an entire `Grid`, too (which is what I had originally wanted to use so as to better control the frame and dividers.